# While editing dialogue, what tool do you use to eliminate clicks within words?

Tags: pro-tools, dialogue, editing, techniques, software

In order to eliminate clicks in words in Pro Tools, and I use either the Pencil Tool or cut out a cycle of the waveform.

What would software tool would you recommend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm all about [iZotope RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit/rx.html).  It's such a lifesaver for me.  I do everything from lowering the noise floor on recordings, removing clicks and clipping, to removing a cough from a live music performance (I actually got that one to work perfectly!!  I'll have to see if I can find the original and final to let you guys A/B the two).

[image: iZotope RX]
<sub>(source: [izotope.com](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/RX/images/declicker_ss.jpg))</sub>

If it's something really tiny and don't want to spend time in RX (it can be very time consuming for more complex fixes), I'll go with the old pencil tool trick.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! So Izotope RX will take clicks out of a voice without artifacts?

Comment: +1 for RX. Amazing tool. 
And the ProTools Pencil! Love it :)
I use the wacom tablet to do editing... much easier (once you get used to it)!

Comment: Hi! Could you please post some video about editing by tablet? Thanks a lot because I can't find anything about it...do you think that a tablet could work even with other sequencer as Nuendo, Cubase or Samplitude? thanks!

Comment: +1 again for RX - since I brought I have used it in some capacity everyday :)

Answer (score 5):

Try these:

Waves [X-Click and X-Crackle](https://www.waves.com/bundles/restoration)

[Izotope Rx](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/rx.html)

Note: Izotope has a full-featured demo that you can audition before you buy to see if it will work for your needs.

[image: Waves X-Click]
<sub>(source: [waves.com](http://www.waves.com/objects/Images/Screenshots%5Csshot_big_x_click01.jpg))</sub>

[image: Waves X-Crackle]
<sub>(source: [waves.com](http://www.waves.com/objects/Images/Screenshots%5Csshot_big_x_crackle01.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I have X-Click but can't get it to not artifact a voice. Have you had any luck using it on a voice to remove mouth noise?

Answer (score 4):

I started out with the pencil tool like the other guys until where I work bought iZotope RX. To clean up clicks etc it is an amazing tool and worth every penny if you can buy it.

Comment: On voice as well? I am such a stickler for quality of the voice and I hate to add artifacts to it if I can avoid it. So, would you even use Izotope RX on a featured voice-over that is louder than everything else?

Comment: Obviously if removing the click entirely lessened the quality of the voice I wouldn't. Sometimes I meet a compromise if the noise affects the enunciation of the voice. Sometimes it is preferable to leave the click in as to remove it would be too destructive on the performance.

It's about choices. The enunciation comes first, then sound quality of the voice in my books.

Answer (score 2):

I check if the job can be done with iZotope RX. It works very well. If I have more serious problems I use the pencil tool in Sony Sound Forge.

Answer (score 2):

Editing out a cycle using protools in shuffle mode is efficient. *Unless you are working with picture.*

I switch to the Pencil tool only when the above method doesn't cut the mustard.

Comment: That's exactly what I do!

Answer (score 1):

When i really want to get that click out manually, i cut and paste. Each phoneme tends to have a repeating wave cycle, so i zoom in til i see the wave and grab one of the cycles before or after, and paste it over. A small crossfade may be necessary. The pencil tool only lowers the amplitude of the click, it doesn't completely get rid of it.

It's only really good for glitchy clicks, as clicks recorded in the space will have a reverb tail.

Answer (score 1):

Slice out the click, then cut and time stretch (TCE) the region before to cover the whole and xfade.

Answer (score 1):

Pencil or cycle copy-paste for me...

Answer (score 1):

For quick "one click" click removal, the old Sonnox Declicker is outstanding - haven't used their new one, though...

For "musical clicks" I like to use iZotope's Spectral Repair - amazing flexibility in certain situations.

Can't beat good old room tone fill for a lot of clicks... it all depends on the time you have and the "type" of click you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't have the budget to try out any nice plugins, but pencil tool in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

If editing in Protools then I'll mainly cut out cycles over using the pencil tool, but I'll use that if needs be. If I'm working to picture, then I just take a little more time to check that the sync's not been compromised. After all - picture work is mainly FPS and cutting out a cycle is tiny samples.

If I have a really clicky piece then I'll use Audition as I've recently been introduced to the spectral editing tool which is, on one hand, cheating (ie not using your ears) and on the other as fast as lightning.

I'll have a proper look into XClick though :)